# How to create one equation to fit all in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to do a formula that I can use in all cells to achieve this(cell = left header + top header)
Usually when you pull the cell to the next one it will change the formula, but it didn't work for me
how can I do this to all cells in the grid?

[image]

Comment: I think formula should be `=A7+F1`

Comment: @Mrig No, because if he copy+paste it in the cell below it will be `=A8+F2`, `F2` is unwanted here. The posted answer is the correct one.

Comment: Got it, didn't understand your question properly at first go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to write formula for cell `B2` like this `=B$1+$A2`, then copy down and to the right. In the example reference will be fixed for column `B`, however reference for `A` will change. Similar reference principle will be applied for rows.
You can lock/unlock the reference by hitting `F4` when cursor is cell reference.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$` to lock the column and/or row in the reference so that when you copy the formula to another cell the references prefixed with `$` will not change, for example:

```
=$A7+F$1
```

This will lock the reference to `Column A` but not the row reference for `A7`. It also locks the reference to `Row 1` in `F1` so that the row reference will not change but the column reference still can.

Comment: Thanks, I chosen the other answer for mentioning the F4 function and extra gfx